# Rich text box link With space

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, hyperlink, richtextbox

I am using richtextbox in my application.
In that i provide one file explorer link. when clicks that link it open the corresponding location.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    string link = string.Empty;
    public Form1()
    {

        link = "file://D:\\Lenovo\\OneKey App\\OneKey Recovery";
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //richTextBox1.Text = "C:\SVN";
        richTextBox1.Font = new Font("Consolas", 20f, FontStyle.Bold);
        richTextBox1.BackColor = Color.LightGray;
        richTextBox1.Text = link;
        richTextBox1.AppendText("\n Clicks the above link & learn about richtext box.");
    }


    private void richTextBox1_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkClickedEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("Explorer.exe", link);
    }
}
```

this is my code. It correctly works. But if there is any space in folder name means it does show the full link in rich text box.

**My result:**

> "file://D:\Lenovo\OneKey" App\OneKey Recovery

The link is shows upto onekey only. other text is looks like normal richbox text.
How to make the entire text as link if the link text has space.?

Comment: Use a non-breaking space to keep the text together: richTextBox1.Text = link.Replace(' ', '\u00a0');

Comment: As an aside, you should use verbatim strings for file paths as they are much more readable. link = @"file://D:\Lenovo\OneKey App\OneKey Recovery";

Answer (score 1):

You can temporally replace the white-space for one of the unicode spaces like for example **U+2000** to avoid that conflict:

```
richTextBox1.Text = link.Replace(' ', ' ');
```

**[Unicode Spaces](https://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/chars/spaces.html)**